# How to present empty relationship in JSONAPI?

Tags: json-api

Looked at http://jsonapi.org/format/ but don't see any description about empty relationship format, for example:

```
{
  "type": "articles",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "title": "Rails is Omakase"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "comments": {
        "data": []
      }
  }
}
```

This `article` doesn't have `comments`, what is the correct way to present a empty relationship?

`"data": []` or `"data": null` or no `"relationships"` at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's described in [resource linkage](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) chapter of JSON API specification:

> Resource linkage MUST be represented as one of the following:
>
> - null for empty to-one relationships.
> - an empty array ([]) for empty to-many relationships.
> - a single resource identifier object for non-empty to-one relationships.
> - an array of resource identifier objects for non-empty to-many relationships.

Note that you don't have to use *resource linkage* at all. You could also use *relationship links*. You could find more information about that one in [this part](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) of specification.

Comment: I would like to highlight that this is related to compound documents (a document with included resource objects). The API does not explicitly specify how to represent empty relationships in non-compound documents. IMHO it´s ok to omit the relationship if it´s empty. But that would prevent discoverability of the API.

Comment: @FranzDeschler Compound documents require full linkage _only_ for included resources. `data` for a relationship may not be included even if it is a compound document. In edge case if sparse fieldsets even if the related resource is included. This is an exception from full linkage requirement. But the important point is: a not included relationship does not mean there aren't any related resources. It is not clear from response payload. So it is very different from explicitly stating that an relationship is empty.